# Performing Date Addition in Query in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

What is the least costly way to perform the following query that returns all documents within a collection that have an endDate x days old in MongoDB?
I am trying to perform something similar to DATEADD in Microsoft T-SQL.

db.collection.find( {endDate: {$gte: ISODate()-x days} }  )

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a `DATEADD` equivalent in MongoDB, but since the query is JavaScript, you can do something like:

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - X))
```

Replace `X` with the number of days. So your query would look like:

```
db.collection.find( { endDate: { $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - X)) } } )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript:

```
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
db.collection.find( {endDate: {$gte: yesterday} } )
```

Comment: Mongo shell can run JavaScript, and it works on the first of every month and on the first of the year. Try it.